# How to set output to MB/GB before issuing FORFILES @fsize command?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to set the command line to display filesize in MB/GB before running a [forfiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forfiles) command?
I am using the forfiles command, but it is displaying in bytes.
The number of digits get quite large when dealing with multi-gigabyte files/directories.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, none shown in at [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx).

Wish I had a better answer for you, but the only way I can see is to [grep](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) it through a script to parse it out and if the filesize position is longer than 9 bytes then convert to GB, if longer than 6 bytes convert to GB. That, of course, if beyond what FORFILES can do, som maybe someone here has dissected the command and found a way to do it within FORFILES?